# Twilio does not post to my webhook on incoming calls

Tags: twilio, webhooks, twilio-api

- I have a trial account.
- I have set up my webhook url in the number console.

[image]

- I have set up a node server tunnelled with ngrok.

But when i call my twilio number, twilio does not send response to my
url. Even in the logs, the Request Inspector for all incoming call is
empty.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is a trail account you need to press a key once the call is answered by Twilio to acknowledge it is a trial account before it will execute any TwiML.

Comment: yes Alan, thanks for the info. I will be accepting your answer. Also is there any way I can test this (pressing the key) using twilio outgoing call instead of using an actual phone

Comment: You can place calls to Twilio WebRTC registered end-points and SIP End-points (in addition to public switched Telephone - i.e. PSTN endpoints), but you still need to press a key to play out the TwiM with a trial account. There are various quickstarts on using the Twilio Client for JavaScript and setting up a SIP Phone to register with Twilio, https://www.twilio.com/blog/registering-sip-phone-twilio-inbound-outbound.